# Moodle block visibility per role on quiz attempt page

Tags: plugins, block, moodle

I have been following [this](https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Blocks) tutorial successfully and created a small custom block.

I need this block to display on maths quiz/attempt.php pages but I have two problems.

- The block displays for the admin user **but does not display for students**
- How do I display the block only on selected quizes i:e maths and not english quizes

  **CODE:**

```
class block_customfeedback extends block_base {
    public function init() {
        $this->title = get_string('customfeedback', 'block_customfeedback');
    }

    public function get_content() {
        if ($this->content !== null) {
          return $this->content;
        }

        $form .= "<form action='http://www.remoteserver.com/response.php' method='post'>";
        $form .= "<label>Question ID</label>    <input name='QuestionID' id='questionid' type='text' />";
        $form .= "<label>Quiz Name</label>      <input name='QuizName' id='quizname' type='text' />";
        $form .= "<label>Your Feedback</label>  <textarea name='Feedback' id='feedback' type='text' ></textarea>";
        $form .= "<input type='submit' value='Submit' />";
        $form .= "</form>";

        $this->content         =  new stdClass;
        $this->content->text   = $form;
        // $this->content->footer = 'Footer here...';

        return $this->content;
    }

    public function applicable_formats() {
        return array(
            'all'   => true
        );
    }

} // close class
```

Comment: Can you show the code?

Comment: @RussellEngland: It's been almost a year and I've gone full cycle in re-developing my Moodle website only to get stuck on the same problem. Apologies for the delay in providing the code but if  you are still interested in helping, I would appreciate your suggestions

Answer (score 0):

You can make your block visible on quiz attempt page.

Steps:

1. Go to your quiz settings page.
2. Click on appearance
3. Click on show more
4. Change the value of "Show blocks during quiz attempts" to Yes.

Now login with student and check.